# Key Error while setting width of column - OpenPyXL

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am getting an error when setting the width of a column

```
workbook = Workbook()

#Add a sheet
worksheet = workbook.active

worksheet.column_dimensions["C"].width = 60.0
```

Here is the error.

```
KeyError: 'C'
```

Answer (score 10):

There is no column "C" to resize.

Verify this with:

```
worksheet.columns
```

If you first create a cell in column C:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
_cell = ws.cell(row=1, column=3)
```

You can then resize it, and not throw a KeyError:

```
ws.column_dimensions["C"].width = 60.0
```

Comment: Might you have an idea what's the issue here Jefe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642026/column-widths-of-some-columns-in-openpyxl-become-zero-after-60-columns

Answer (score -1):

Change the dimensions of the column after you finish writing to the excel sheet.

```
for col in worksheet.columns:
     worksheet.column_dimensions[col[0].column].width = 20.0
```